# jQuery News Ticker - not working on my site

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

I'm trying to use the jQuery news ticker code from http://www.jquerynewsticker.com but seem to be unable to make it work.

I've reviewed the code on the code's home page, reviewed / compared my markup and code placement, tried to follow the code with Firebug and it still doesn't function. Perhaps I've made a mistake somewhere but I can't find it or perhaps there's some other thing I've missed.

I've put the code I'm using at:

http://www.homes-in-naperville.com/banana.html

I would welcome comments that would help me lead to a solution to get it working.

Comment: Please take another look at http://www.jquerynewsticker.com to see exactly how to implement the ticker in JavaScript. You're missing the basic code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. In the source of my original link I have included the direct copies of the:

Comment: Oops. Thank you.

In the source of my original link/page I have already included links to locally hosted copies of the:

news ticker css - that gave me some generic formatting
news ticker js file - the ticker code

In addition I have injected inline my variables (newsheadline) and a link to my code that passes the id to the ticker() function and that is wrapped in a jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });.

In that configuration the ticker code fires, runs, processes but does not generate any ticker-like output it just displays the first LI item statically.
 
What basic code am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript on your site you have put the javascript directly in the page without the DOM ready handler, and also the syntax is a little off.

Change it to the following and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ticker').ticker({
            speed: "0.10",
            pauseOnItems: "5000",
            fadeInSpeed: "600",
            fadeOutSpeed: "900"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks

As I said in the other comment in my original link I have my code wrapped in a jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... }) block.

I see the ticker() code being called when tracking it through Firebug I just can't work out where it 'breaks' and stops or which part of my code or markup is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

attach this script to your site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```